# How to maintain state for a turn-based game in django

Tags: design, design-patterns, networking, django

I am using django to develop a turn based chess variant. I just finished using django-channels to create a lobby and match 2 players together. Now, I need to make them play each other and I'm thinking about what the best way to design these interactions is.

1. The first idea is to have each client store their own state, and send the deltas through a shared websocket channel. This works, but then I don't really know the game state and I'm not sure how worried I should be about a websocket failing to send a message and then letting game state get out of sync.
2. So, to maintain the game state, I could create another model in Django which contains all of the information about the current game state. Each time a move comes in, I delete the old game state, generate a new state from the change, and then create a new game state. This method seems alright, but it feels somewhat awkward to hit the database and completely remove/recreate a game state each time. More importantly, it will be annoying to serialize game state since I have custom pieces with custom effects that the user can code by placing some blocks together on the frontend - if I make it so that the effects can include changing the moveset of a piece on the board, then I need to also serialize all of the pieces as well, and so it'll become harder to add features.
3. What I feel will be easiest to work with (although perhaps harder to set up) is to create a python thread and have it join the websocket channel with the other 2 players. Then this process can have an instance of a python class which will be easier to modify than a Django model. I'm not sure how to go about this though because there weren't any examples in the docs - do I just start a new python thread in django when the match starts and then make a websocket with that thread? And will it be problematic to start one thread per game if I try to scale to more players?

(Note: I want to make something scalable even if it's incredibly likely that my game never gets popular because I like writing good code)

Currently I'm leaning towards 3 a tiny bit more than 2 and 2 a lot more than 1, but there is a lot I don't really understand since I haven't done much much with syncing multiple different people before, so I was wondering if there are other issues/advantages I won't realize until 3 days into development and if there is a recommended choice for my application.

Comment: If the user can customize at the front-end which moves a piece can take (which is part of the rules of the game), how do you ensure that the two players use the same set of rules?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I use blockly to allow users to program rules, then I serialize the workspace and save the moves to my database. I will need to write code to translate the workspace into [python and/or js], then I execute that code. Technically users could inspect-element and mess things up in scenario 1, but everyone knows the same rules because they are stored in the database.